# Eclipse Method Information Creation

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

[Visual Example of what I wish to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vD8Q.png)

When creating a method in the java language on the Eclipse IDE, How do you make it so you get the information(yellow) about your method(white)?

Sometimes I forget the exact meaning of my methods and it would be nice to keep my comments.

(This should go without needing to be said but I am wanting the descriptions when I call my mehtods in other files.)

More info::

```
FileA.java{
 classA{
   classA(){}
   //Generic comment
   MethodA(){}
 }
}

FileB.java{
  MehtodB(){
    classA a = new classA();
    a.mehtodA(); ----->I should see //Generic comment when typing in this
  }
}
```

Comment: http://www.drjava.org/docs/user/ch10.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called 'javadoc'. It looks like so:

```
/**
 * This is javadoc.
 * Note the double star start.
 *
 * You can {@code place some} tags in here for formatting.
 *
 * @param name User's full name, in title case, as they prefer to be called.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If name is blank
 */
public void setName(String name) {
 ...
}
```

'javadoc tutorial' is a good thing to search the web for, presumably :)

Note that javadoc is not stored in class files; it is stored separately. If you use e.g. maven to distribute dependencies you can ship a separate jar with the javadoc included, the `javadoc` tool can make HTML for you (but eclipse and co don't need this). Generally, you either link the javadoc (maven does this for you, otherwise, right click a dependency and you can associate a source jar or javadoc jar), or if it's source files, eclipse just figures it out.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your detailed answer with examples. I just tested this in eclipse IDE for Enterprise 2020 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I got your question right. I think what you need is the 'documentation comment' which is a type of comment that you add right above your method. For example:

```
/** 
 * The add() method returns addition of given numbers.
 */  
public static int add(int a, int b){
     return a+b;
}
```

When you are navigating this method, you'll be prompted with the comment.